# Can't run parallel jobs in Heritrix3 Web Crawler

Tags: linux, bash, web-crawler, heritrix

I created 2 jobs in **Heritrix 3.2.0** and I launched both after building, both started running but after 15 to 20 seconds, one job is stopped and other continues and when a job is stopped, the status in jobs log is as follows:

> 2015-05-12T06:40:33.715Z INFO EMPTY 20150512063923

So could not multi-process the jobs. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

No it just means that this job is done (queue is empty). If no pages were downloaded, it probably means that your decide rules are too strict and don't allow anything to be downloaded.